# Python Null-Safe IN (Substring) and LEN (Length)

Tags: python

I couldn't find a concise and idiomatic way to quickly do None/NULL-safe checks on `len` and `in`. For example, `in` is not NULL-safe.

I'm checking whether an attribute of the 0th element of the dictionary `agreements` has a substring. The dict itself and its attribute could both be `None`. I can write

```
if agreements != None and len(agreements) > 0 and 
   agreements[0].action_taken != None and 'system' in agreements[0].action_taken:
   # ... some action ...
```

But I would prefer a more concise way. Is it available?

Comment: use `is not` rather than `!=` for None checks

Comment: also `if agreements` can be used instead of `if len(agreements)>0`

Comment: Two comments.   FIrst `if agreements` covers both `agreements is None` and `len(agreements) > 0`.  Second, just try `'system' in ....` and wrap it in a try/except block that looks for a `NullPointerException`.  That's the Python way.

Comment: Yes but the NPE check is really messy. This condition is already an extra clausein my outer `If` and I'd hate to make it even more complex.

Answer (score 1):

without any try-except block (which is potentially a better idea), you're code could essentially be written as:

```py
if agreements \
    and agreements[0].action_taken \
    and 'system' in agreements[0].action_taken:
   # ... some action ...
```

Using walrus `:=` operator in Python 3.8 simplifies this a bit:

```py
if agreements \
    and ((action := agreements[0].action_taken) and 'system' in action):
    # ... some action ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my answer above

```
try:
    if 'system' in agreements[0].action_taken:
      ....
except (TypeError, AttributeError):
    pass
```

---

Edited to remove NullPointerException.  I was confusing Java and Python.

Comment: Not keen on this solution because it introduces error handling where there was none, and also my If clause is already part of a larger If which I don't want to make even more complex.

Comment: I still think error handling is a good solution here. It introduces almost no performance impact, and in fact is a bit more efficient than checking if `agreements` is a non-empty list, assuming ofc that this is generally the case.

Comment: Ignoring `TypeError` and `AttributeError` in an entire block of code risks hiding bugs in the future. Also, `NullPointerException` isn’t a thing.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Got my language confused.  I'll fix.   And the try/except is around a very small amount of code in which pretty much nothing else can go wrong.  I'm a strong believer that try/except should be around the smallest amount of code with the most specific errors possible.